# Display IP address from struct ip

Tags: c, pcap

So I have this code right here:

```
void got_packet(u_char* args, struct pcap_pkhdr* hdr, const u_char* packet) {
    struct ether_header* eptr;
    eptr = (struct ether_header*)packet;
    struct ip* ip;
    ip = (struct ip*)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header));

    printf("Source IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));
}
```

If I try to print the ethernet header (MAC addresses), I have no problem.
If I try to print the IP (last line of code), I get this: error: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  printf("Source IP: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip->ip_src));

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your `struct ip` defined ? And where is the code `xip->sin_addr = ip->ip_src;` ?

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong log. I have edited it, very sorry about that.... I'm using the struct ip defined in netinet/ip.h

Comment: Problem solved, thank you. I didn't include everything I needed. Thanks!